# How to run an Open.window event based on var value

Tags: javascript, mobile, gyroscope

Here is the link to my code: [www.parallaxplayground.com/flipside.html](http://www.parallaxplayground.com/flipside.html)
I'm trying to open a new web page when the user's phone is flipped using the variables created by the phone's gyroscope.

```js
        <script>
function init() {
  //Find our div containers in the DOM
  var dataContainerOrientation = document.getElementById('dataContainerOrientation');
  var dataContainerMotion = document.getElementById('dataContainerMotion');
 
 
  //Check for support for DeviceOrientation event
  if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
            var alpha = event.alpha;
            var beta = event.beta;
            var gamma = event.gamma;
           
            if(alpha!=null || beta!=null || gamma!=null) 
              dataContainerOrientation.innerHTML = 'alpha: ' + alpha + '<br/>beta: ' + beta + '<br />gamma: ' + gamma;
          }, false);
  }
  
 
 
  // Check for support for DeviceMotion events
  if(window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(event) {
            var x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
            var y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
            var z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
            
            var r = event.rotationRate;
            var html = 'Acceleration:<br />';
            html += 'x: ' + x +'<br />y: ' + y + '<br/>z: ' + z+ '<br />';
            html += 'Rotation rate:<br />';
            if(r!=null) html += 'alpha: ' + r.alpha +'<br />beta: ' + r.beta + '<br/>gamma: ' + r.gamma + '<br />';
            if (y > 7)   
         {  
             window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
             };
            dataContainerMotion.innerHTML = html;     
            
          });
  }
  
 
}   
</script>
```

You'll have to test it on your phone. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I'd be surprised if a rotation was a sufficiently affirmative event to avoid the rules for when browsers should block popups.

Comment: I was able to get document.write('hello world') to work. I just can't get window.open to work.

Comment: Ah, that suggests my speculation was right.

Comment: Anyway to fix this or am I just SOL?

Comment: I suspect there is no way to open a popup in response to rotating the device (and speaking as a user, I'm glad of it, that sounds really annoying).

Comment: What about an alert? I'm trying to make a website that when you flip your phone it gives you the "flip side" of an argument. I know cheesy.

Comment: Instead of opening a new page. Could I just move the page to a different div. Like reference an ID to jump to?